# Logarithmic inequality: $7^{\sqrt{2x}}>20$

Tags: inequality, logarithms

We're working on logs and exponents in class, but I've never dealt with a situation where the equation isn't an equation but an inequality. Any help on how to solve this?! Thanks!

$$7^{\sqrt{2x}}>20$$

Comment: $log_a(x)$ is strictly increasing function(a any positive number), which means x<y implies $log_a(x)<log_a(y)$.

Answer (score 2):

$$
7^{\sqrt{2x}} > 20.
$$
If the base of the logarithmic function is bigger than $1$, rather than between $0$ and $1$, then the logarithmic function is increasing rather than decreasing.  Consequently in the following step, "$>$" remains "$>$" rather than becoming "$<$":
$$
\log \left(7^{\sqrt{2x}}\right) > \log 20.
$$
$$
\sqrt{2x}\log 7 > \log 20.
$$
If the base of the logarithmic function is bigger than $1$, rather than between $0$ and $1$, then the logarithm of $7$ is positive.  It is for that reason that "$>$" remains "$>$" in the next step rather than changing to "$<$":
$$
\sqrt{2x} >\frac{\log 20}{\log 7} = \log_7 20.
$$
The next step works because the squaring function, applied to positive numbers, is increasing.  If it were decreasing, then "$>$" would change to "$<$":
$$
2x>\left(\log_7 20\right)^2
$$
Finally
$$
x>\frac 1 2 \left(\log_7 20\right)^2.
$$
(And here we relied on the fact that $\dfrac12$ is positive.)

Answer (score 1):

$$\sqrt{2x}\ln7>\ln{20}\Rightarrow \sqrt{2x}>\frac{\ln20}{\ln7}\Rightarrow x>(\frac{\ln20}{\ln7})^2/2$$

Don't seem to be much different from an equation.

Comment: How do you mean doesn't seem much different to an equation? Plus this is NOT an answer a "lazy" or "stupid" person would give ;)

Comment: I mean the method of calculation doesn't differ in this case. But by reading the other answers I see that there are cases where it does that I was not aware of.

Hehe well... :) It is meant to be in jest mostly. But seeing all the other people here with so much knowledge makes you feel a bit overwhelmed.

Answer (score 1):

Logarithms to any base are functions that are strictly increasing, i.e. $$x>y\implies \log(x)>\log(y).$$ What this means in your case, is that you can "take the $\log$ of both sides", and preserve the inequality. So:

\begin{align*}
7^\sqrt{2x} &> 20 \\
\iff \log(7^\sqrt{2x}) &> \log(20) \\
\iff \sqrt{2x} \log(7) &> \log(20) \\
\iff \sqrt{2x} &> \frac{\log(20)}{\log(7)}
\end{align*}

We want to square both sides, but we must be careful ($-3<1$, but $(-3)^2>1^2$). Thankfully, $\frac{\log(20)}{\log(7)}>0$, so both sides of the inequality are positive, so the inequality is preserved when we square.

\begin{align*}
\iff 2x &> \left(\frac{\log(20)}{\log(7)}\right)^2 \\
\iff x &> \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\log(20)}{\log(7)}\right)^2
\end{align*}